# Is it possible to use Eclipse Editor in my application

Tags: eclipse, editor

Is there a compact way to extract eclipse editor as a stand-alone component and add it to another application?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SWT/JFace outside of the Eclipse framework to make a similar editor, but you can't just pull out an Eclipse component and stick it in a completely different program. You would have to use the RCP framework to use it as-is.

Comment: where can i find those packages? i have tried to copy and include jar files i found in eclipse/plugins directory, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I've never done it myself, but I would imagine what you described should work. I have however had trouble getting jars to be recognized though. Sometimes I'll change nothing and it will just start working. Make sure they're on the build path (that might be what you meant by 'include'), clean the project, and/or restart your IDE.